# known devnet validators

Tags: validator, devnet

Is this this right list of known devnet validators to start with? I'm starting one, but ending up over 135k blocks behind to start with.

```
--known-validator dv1ZAGvdsz5hHLwWXsVnM94hWf1pjbKVau1QVkaMJ92 \
--known-validator dv2eQHeP4RFrJZ6UeiZWoc3XTtmtZCUKxxCApCDcRNV \
--known-validator dv4ACNkpYPcE3aKmYDqZm9G5EB3J4MRoeE7WNDRBVJB \
--known-validator dv3qDFk1DTF36Z62bNvrCXe9sKATA6xvVy6A798xxAS \
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct for devnet per https://docs.solana.com/clusters#example-solana-validator-command-line. If you're ending up so far behind to start, you may be getting an old snapshot, or the hardware may not be enough.

Either way, be sure to use the same version as the devnet nodes, which is 1.14.16 as of this writing:

```
$ solana validators --url devnet
...
Stake By Version:
1.16.0  -    1 current validators ( 0.00%)
1.15.2  -    1 current validators ( 0.00%)
1.14.16 -    4 current validators (74.98%)
1.14.15 -    1 current validators (24.99%)
1.14.13 -    0 current validators ( 0.00%)   1 delinquent validators ( 0.00%)
1.14.12 -    3 current validators ( 0.01%)
1.13.3  -    0 current validators ( 0.00%)   1 delinquent validators ( 0.00%)
unknown -    0 current validators ( 0.00%)  26 delinquent validators ( 0.02%)
```

Comment: updating the version solved the problem - thank you